# JavaCPP problems compiling the example

Tags: javacpp

I just wanted to test JAVACPP and tried the first example from the webpage within my eclipse:

http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/
(LegacyClass and LegacyLibrary)

As soon as I type:

> javac -cp libs\javacpp.jar:. src\LegacyLibrary.java

into the commandline I get the following error message:

> src\LegacyLibrary.java:1: error: package com.googlecode.javacpp does
>   not exist import com.googlecode.javacpp.*;
>
> src\LegacyLibrary.java:2: error: package
>   com.googlecode.javacpp.annotation does not exist  import
>   com.googlecode.javacpp.annotation.*;
>
> src\LegacyLibrary.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
>   @Platform(include="LegacyLibrary.h")
>
> symbol: class Platform src\LegacyLibrary.java:5: error: cannot find
>   symbol @Namespace("LegacyLibrary")
>
> symbol: class Namespace src\LegacyLibrary.java:7: error: cannot find
>   symbol
>       public static class LegacyClass extends Pointer {
>                           symbol:   class Pointer location: class LegacyLibrary src\LegacyLibrary.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
>   public native @ByRef String get_property(); public native void
>   set_property(String property);
>                            symbol:   class ByRef   location: class LegacyClass src\LegacyLibrary.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>           public native @ByRef String property();     public native void property(String property);
>                             symbol:   class ByRef   location: class LegacyClass src\LegacyLibrary.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
>           static { Loader.load(); }
>
> symbol:   variable Loader   location: class LegacyClass 8 errors

Why do I get it?

Is it possible to use JavaCPP not having *.cpp and *.h file, but just having a *.dll file?
Or what exactly do I need for using this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Windows. Replace the colon ':' by a semi-colon ';'.

Comment: I did not try it, but it makes sense.